# XSLT for transforming XML to JSON (Solr format)

Tags: json, xml, xslt, solr

I'm trying to generate an XSLT to transform an XML file to JSON format, including all necessary fields for proper indexing in Solr.

My current XSLT file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">{
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Object or Element Property-->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="childDoc" select="name(*[1])"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childDoc]) >= 1">
    "Document":"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>", <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
    "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>": <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Array Parent Node -->
        <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayParentNode">
            <xsl:call-template name="Path"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Array Element -->
        <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
            <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Object Properties -->
        <xsl:template name="Properties">
            <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">
    "_childDocuments_":[
    { "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] 
        }
    ]
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="ArrayParentNode"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>                   
        }
        ]
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>

        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Attribute Property -->
        <xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",</xsl:template>

        <!--Path-->
        <xsl:template name = "Path">
            <xsl:variable name="ances" select="ancestor-or-self::node()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ancestros">
                <xsl:for-each select="$ances">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'.')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
        "Path": "<xsl:value-of select = "substring($ancestros,2,string-length($ancestros)-2)"/>",
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the following example:

```
<Reporte>
    <id>10</id>
    <Operacion>
        <id>10.1</id>
        <Tipo_Operacion>Ejemplo</Tipo_Operacion>
        <Fecha>10/10/2010</Fecha>
        <Monto>12345</Monto>
    </Operacion>
    <bla>123456ytgfde</bla>
    <Persona_Fisica>
        <id>10.2</id>
        <Nombre>Juan</Nombre>
        <Apellido>Perez</Apellido>
        <Domicilio>
            <id>10.2.1</id>
            <Calle>Yrigoyen</Calle>
            <Numero>123</Numero>
        </Domicilio>
        <Telefono>
            <id>10.2.2</id>
            <Prefijo>11</Prefijo>
            <Numero>12345678</Numero>
        </Telefono>
    </Persona_Fisica>
    <Persona_Fisica>
        <id>10.3</id>
        <Nombre>Roberto Carlos</Nombre>
        <Apellido>De Souza</Apellido>
        <PEP>true</PEP>
        <Domicilio>
            <id>10.3.1</id>
            <Calle>Falsa</Calle>
            <Numero>678</Numero>
        </Domicilio>
        <Telefono>
            <id>10.3.2</id>
            <Prefijo>11</Prefijo>
            <Numero>87654321</Numero>
        </Telefono>
    </Persona_Fisica>
    <Persona_Juridica>
        <id>10.4</id>
        <Denominacion>Lavado SRL</Denominacion>
        <CUIT>23-32480636-9</CUIT>
    </Persona_Juridica>
</Reporte>
```

My output is the following:

```
{

                "Document":"Reporte", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte",

                "id": "11",
                "Document":"Operacion", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Operacion",

                "id": "10.1",
                "Tipo_Operacion": "Ejemplo",
                "Fecha": "10/10/2010",
                "Monto": "12345"                    
        }
        ]
                ,
                "bla": "123456ytgfde",
                "Document":"Persona_Fisica", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica",

                "id": "10.2",
                "Nombre": "Juan",
                "Apellido": "Perez",
                "Document":"Domicilio", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Domicilio",

                "id": "10.2.1",
                "Calle": "Yrigoyen",
                "Numero": "123"                 
        }
        ]
                ,
                "Document":"Telefono", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Telefono",

                "id": "10.2.2",
                "Prefijo": "11",
                "Numero": "12345678"                    
        }
        ]

        }
        ]
                ,
                "Document":"Persona_Fisica", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica",

                "id": "10.3",
                "Nombre": "Roberto Carlos",
                "Apellido": "De Souza",
                "PEP": "true",
                "Document":"Domicilio", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Domicilio",

                "id": "10.3.1",
                "Calle": "Falsa",
                "Numero": "678"                 
        }
        ]
                ,
                "Document":"Telefono", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Telefono",

                "id": "10.3.2",
                "Prefijo": "11",
                "Numero": "87654321"                    
        }
        ]

        }
        ]
                ,
                "Document":"Persona_Juridica", 
    "_childDocuments_":[
        {

        "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Juridica",

                "id": "10.4",
                "Denominacion": "Lavado SRL",
                "CUIT": "23-32480636-9"                 
        }
        ]

        }
        ]
                }
```

Disregarding indentation (as it is desirable but not required), I would expect something like the following:

```
{
    "Document": "Reporte",
    "Path": "Reporte",
    "id": "12",
    "bla": "123456ytgfde",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "Document": "Operacion",
            "Path": "Reporte.Operacion",
            "id": "10.1",
            "Tipo_Operacion": "Ejemplo",
            "Fecha": "10/10/2010",
            "Monto": "12345"
        },
        {
            "Document": "Persona_Fisica",
            "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica",
            "id": "10.2",
            "Nombre": "Juan",
            "Apellido": "Perez",
            "_childDocuments_": [
                {
                    "Document": "Domicilio",
                    "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Domicilio",
                    "id": "10.2.1",
                    "Calle": "Yrigoyen",
                    "Numero": "123"
                },
                {
                    "Document": "Telefono",
                    "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Telefono",
                    "id": "10.2.2",
                    "Prefijo": "11",
                    "Numero": "12345678"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Document": "Persona_Fisica",
            "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica",
            "id": "10.3",
            "Nombre": "Roberto Carlos",
            "Apellido": "De Souza",
            "PEP": "true",
            "_childDocuments_": [
                {
                    "Document": "Domicilio",
                    "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Domicilio",
                    "id": "10.3.1",
                    "Calle": "Falsa",
                    "Numero": "678"
                },
                {
                    "Document": "Telefono",
                    "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Fisica.Telefono",
                    "id": "10.3.2",
                    "Prefijo": "11",
                    "Numero": "87654321"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Document": "Persona_Juridica",
            "Path": "Reporte.Persona_Juridica",
            "id": "10.4",
            "Denominacion": "Lavado SRL",
            "CUIT": "23-32480636-9"
        }
    ]
}
```

Summarizing, what's still missing from my XSLT:

1. Elements within "Reporte" that do not have any sub-elements (as
   "Document": "Reporte", "Path": "Reporte", "id": "10", "bla":
   "123456ytgfde") should be outside the first *childDocuments*
   element.
2. Only a single *childDocuments* element with multiple
   sub-documents should be created instead of one per sub-document.
3. "Document" element should be after the corresponding
   *childDocuments* instead of before (side by side with the "Path" element, which is ok).
4. Pretty indentation (just desirable).

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1? Does the order of properties in your JSON matter? XSLT 3 (available since 2017) has JSON support and serialization built-in so you could easily write templates there creating XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 maps and arrays and serialize them as `json`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5S for an example.

Comment: I'm usign the TransformXML Processor in Nifi, and I cannot find which XSLT version it runs nowhere. However, I tried to run the transformation you attached and it ended in an error, so I guess it doesn't support XSLT 3.

Comment: If possible, it would be better to solve it with XSLT 1.

Comment: "I'm usign the TransformXML Processor in Nifi, and I cannot find which XSLT version it runs nowhere": any XSLT processor allows you to run a stylesheet that outputs e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` to find out.

Comment: https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=nifi.git;a=blob;f=nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/pom.xml;h=4c90f8a925062f4bd026af9ade5c6b23f6ae5aae;hb=98aabf2c50f857efc72fd6f2bfdd9965b97fa195 seems to suggest they include Saxon HE, it seems 9.6 at least, so you should have XSLT 2 support. Might be easy to use XSLT 3 instead if you drop Saxon 9.9 or 9.8 HE from Maven or Sourceforge on your Nifi classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move to XSLT 3 you can use the built-in support for XML to JSON conversion (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json), for instance by creating the XML representation of JSON specified in the XSLT 3 spec and then calling the `xml-to-json` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-xml-to-json) on that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:mode name="json" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="json">
      <fn:map>
          <fn:string key="Document">{local-name()}</fn:string>
          <fn:string key="Path">{string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/local-name(), '.')}</fn:string>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" mode="#current"/>
          <xsl:where-populated>
              <fn:array key="_childDocument_">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]" mode="#current"/>
              </fn:array>
          </xsl:where-populated>
      </fn:map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]" mode="json">
      <fn:string key="{local-name()}">{.}</fn:string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5S/2

As you also asked for an XSLT 1 solution, at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5S/8 I have tried to reuse the XSLT 3 templates to transform your XML into the XML format specified into the XSLT 3 spec to represent JSON, only this time using pure XSLT 1, then I have added some templates to try to serialize that XML in XSLT 1 as JSON text, using `exsl:node-set` to transform the intermediary result tree fragment into a node-set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn exsl"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="indent" select="'  '"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="json">
      <xsl:param name="path" select="''"/>
      <xsl:variable name="current-path">
          <xsl:if test="ancestor::*">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($path, '.')"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <fn:map>
          <fn:string key="Document">
              <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          </fn:string>
          <fn:string key="Path">
              <xsl:value-of select="$current-path"/>
          </fn:string>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" mode="json"/>
          <xsl:if test="*[*]">
              <fn:array key="_childDocument_">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]" mode="json">
                      <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$current-path"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </fn:array>
          </xsl:if>
      </fn:map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]" mode="json">
      <fn:string key="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </fn:string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <!--
      <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($json-xml)/node()"/>
      <hr/>
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($json-xml)/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:map">
      <xsl:param name="current-indent" select="''"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,&#10;</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($current-indent, '{&#10;')"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:with-param name="current-indent" select="concat($current-indent, $indent)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;', $current-indent, '}')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key]">
      <xsl:param name="current-indent"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,&#10;</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($current-indent, '&quot;', @key, '&quot; : [&#10;')"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:with-param name="current-indent" select="concat($current-indent, $indent)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>      
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;', $current-indent, ']')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:string">
      <xsl:param name="current-indent"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,&#10;</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($current-indent, '&quot;', @key, '&quot; : &quot;', ., '&quot;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Considered to the XSLT 3 approach this has several drawbacks, I have made no attempt to implement all the different JSON data types like numbers, booleans, there is only a template for strings, I have made no attempts to ensure that any characters in JSON strings that need to be escaped are properly escaped. And I am sure there are other flaws as it would require wider and rigorous testing, but perhaps it helps you as a step to deal with your data or approach.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I've tested the last XSLT and it works properly. Just a little comment. The correct transformation to be able to process the document with Solr was with _childDocuments_ (in plural) instead of _childDocument_.